# Trouble with insertion of C string into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a program to read a file and then store the data into a linked List.

**linkedList.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct linked_list
{
    char *stock_name;
    double stock_price;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

typedef struct linked_list NODE;

NODE* insert(NODE *head, double stock_price, char *stock_name);
void printList(NODE *head);
```

**linkedList.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include"linkedList.h"

void printList(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *this = head;

    while(this != NULL)
    {
        printf("stock name:%s , stock price:%lf\n", this->stock_name, this->stock_price);
        this = this->next;
    }

}


NODE* insert(NODE *head, double stock_price, char *stock_name)
{
    NODE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->stock_price = stock_price;
        newNode->stock_name = stock_name;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->stock_price = stock_price;
        newNode->stock_name = stock_name;

        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linkedList.h"

NODE *head;
bool headNode = true;

void insertIntoLinkedList(char *stock_name, double stock_price);

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    double stock_price;
    char stock_name[100];
    int stock_name_counter = 0;

    **..then I read the file..**


    stock_name[stock_name_counter] = '\0'; //to end my C string
    stock_name_counter = 0;  //this is used for reading char

    insertIntoLinkedList(stock_name, stock_price); //I double checked here,the name and price is correct
         **......**
    printList(head); //**Not the output I want**
    fclose( file );


void insertIntoLinkedList(char *m_stock_name, double m_stock_price)
{
    if(headNode == true)
    {
        head = insert(NULL, m_stock_price, m_stock_name);
        headNode = false; //this is used to insert data to my linked list for the first time
    }
    else
    {
        head = insert(head, m_stock_price, m_stock_name);
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:  if the file contains:
YAHOO 120
GOOGLE 10
APPLE 199

my printList() gave me this:
APPLE 120
APPLE 10
APPLE 199

I have been trying to debug for hours and still cannot figure why the name is not stored in my linked list properly(but the price is store properly..)...any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Consider moving to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, consider just using [sys/queue.h](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/queue/) instead of pulling your brains out.

Comment: thx, but I would like to try writing my own data structure before I get familiar with C :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of `stock_name` in main is always constant through out the program and you store that address to `newNode->stock_name` and so you will always get the last stored string in `stock_name`.

Modification

```
NODE* insert(NODE *head, double stock_price, char *stock_name)
{
    NODE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode->stock_name = malloc(strlen(stock_name)+1);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->stock_price = stock_price;            
        strcpy(newNode->stock_name, stock_name);
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->stock_price = stock_price;
        strcpy(newNode->stock_name, stock_name);

        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Don't forget to free the allocated memory.

Comment: But when I do the following:
newNode->stock_name inside the insert function, I will still get the correct name, why?

Comment: Because you haven't overwritten the buffer yet. That comes later, when you read the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of the string stored in stock_name when you call insert. As is, all the nodes point to the same buffer, and every time you read a new line,  you overwrite the buffer. In the end, this means that all of the nodes have the text APPLE because that's the last content that's read into the shared buffer. If you either copy the buffer's contents (instead of just the pointer to the buffer) or allocate a new buffer every time you read from the file, this will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that C does not have a "String" type. A string is simple an array of characters, and an array "decays" to a pointer when used as an argument to a function. Based on the way you're using it, your `insert()` function should do a second `malloc()` to allocate storage for the string and use `strdup()` or similar to store it.

Your other problem is that you've got a logic flaw in the `insert()` function. You aren't initializing `newNode->next` if `head` is NULL. You should be doing `newNode->next = head` either way. If it's NULL, good. Your list tail will then not be pointing at an indeterminate place.